# Import objects of a class in a different script

Tags: python, object, import

I have a python folder with multiple scripts. Let's say the name of the folder is Example. THe structure is as follows:

```
Example/ 
    main.py
    classes.py\
        class cls_inp:
            "Some code" 
    UserInterface.py
```

My script runs like this. I call main.py. Within main.py, constants.py is called and the class cls_inp is defined. Then main.py calls the function run() defined within UserInterface.py. UserInterface.py creates objects of the class cls_inp, as objects inp1, inp2 etc.

```
"UserInterface.py"
def run():
    from constants import cls_inp
    inp1 = cls_inp()
    inp2 = cls_inp()
    "Some code that modifies inp1 and inp2"
    " go back to main.py"
```

After this, the code goes back to main.py.

Now, I need to be able to access the objects inp1, and inp2 from main.py. The problem is that I am not able to import the objects, I can only import the class. What is the best way to do this?

P.S: I would prefer a solution without returning the objects to the main function, as I have a lot of class instances in reality.

Answer (score 0):

You can return inp1 and inp2 as an array:

```
"UserInterface.py"
def run():
    from constants import cls_inp
    inp1 = cls_inp()
    inp2 = cls_inp()
    "Some code that modifies inp1 and inp2"
    " go back to main.py"
    return [inp1 , inp2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def run():
    from constants import cls_inp
    inp1 = cls_inp()
    inp2 = cls_inp()
    return (inp1, inp2)

def main():
    inp1, inp2 = UserInterface.run()
```

something like this?
You have to pass the objects outside of the function as return value

Comment: Is it possible to do this without return values? In reality, I have a lot of instances of the class and it will be difficult to return all of them. Also, I need these objects in scripts other than main.py

Comment: If you do not wish to return them, you can simply call `UserInterface.run()` without assigning them. If you need these objects in other scripts, you should pass the objects directly into the other scripts eg. `some_func(inp1):` Otherwise, you will have to make use of `globals()` to manipulate the objects directly in your script.

Comment: If you don't want to have `run` return the values, you have to decide which module `inp1` and `inp2` belong to; Python doesn't have process-wide global variable.